# Json object not displaying in jsp

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page where I am trying to get a JSON object from my servlet.

jsp code:

```
<%@page import="org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>View Json</title>
 <%
   JSONObject jsonObject=(JSONObject)request.getAttribute("jsonObject");
  %>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h6>JSON View</h6>
  <%=jsonObject%>
  </body>
 </html>
```

My java code sends the json object to the above jsp page:

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString.toString());
 request.setAttribute("jsonObject", jsonObj);
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("check.html");
 dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

My jsp page is displaying all scriptlets instead of the json data. Please advice. Thanks.

I see this error in jsp page:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
```

Comment: Try changing the page import to org.json.simple.JSONObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change import statement in jsp

From

```
<%@page import="org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject"%>
```

to

```
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
```